# Many to Many Relationship doesn't work both ways?

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I've been trying to grok EF many-to-many relationships for the past two days now and I'm still missing something even after scouring a dozen different questions here.

I've got a model named `Text` that can have an arbitrary number of `Tag` models associated with it, and obviously, at least in theory, each `Tag` can be associated with an arbitrary number of Texts. Entity Framework seems to understand this well enough to create a table named TextTags in the database without me asking it to do so, and I can access `Text.Tags` without trouble, but when I attempt to access `Tag.Texts` in my code, I get a null reference exception.

Now, I *could* just add every text to every tag manually (or could I? that seems to throw some kind of error), but that would seem to defeat the purpose... Besides which, it also seems error prone. What am I failing to understand?

Code as requested:

Text model:

```
public class Text
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Tag model:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Text> Texts { get; set; }
}
```

Data insert:

```
using (var db = new TextDbContext())
{
    db.Authors.Add(new Author()
    {
        Name = "Poe"
    });

    db.Tags.Add(new Tag() { Name = "lame" });
    db.Tags.Add(new Tag() { Name = "example" });

    db.SaveChanges();

    db.Texts.Add(new Text()
    {
        Author = db.Authors.First(),
        Tags = db.Tags.ToList(),
        Content = "This is the first text by Poe."
    });

    db.Texts.Add(new Text()
    {
        Author = db.Authors.First(),
        Tags = db.Tags.ToList(),
        Content = "This is the second text by Poe."
    });

    db.Texts.Add(new Text()
    {
        Author = db.Authors.First(),
        Tags = db.Tags.ToList(),
        Content = "This is the third text by Poe."
    });

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Error:

```
foreach (var tag in db.Tags)
{
    foreach (var text in tag.Texts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tag: {0}\tText: {1}", tag.Name, text.Content);
        // Null reference on line above.
    }
}
```

Comment: With default loading options (eager loading) that should not happen. Could you post some code that presents the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a `NullReferenceException` because your navigation property `Tag.Texts` is not marked as `virtual`. As a result lazy loading does not work to load the `Tag.Texts` collection when you access it and the collection is `null`. (`Text.Tags` *is* `virtual`, hence no exception here.)

Comment: You, sir, are a born-again genius. Or maybe you were born that way the first time.